# never yet in English

Tags: meaning, usage

> "For never yet has lover lived, but longed to wive, like them that are
> no more alive"

Is "Never yet" grammatical correct? Does it mean "Not Yet"?

**Source : final stanza of Baile and Aillinn, William Butler Yeats.**

Comment: No, both are different actually. The adverb **never** is meaning under no circumstances or no occasions. So in this context, changing *never* to *not* will change the meaning of the prose.

Comment: It's a poetic way of saying "It has never happened yet that...", so, yes, it does mean approximately "not yet".